# Declare global variables and access locally

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, global-variables, environment-variables

I have two assignments/variables in my code:

```
OUTPUT1="/Users/check/1.html"
OUTPUT2="/Users/check/2.html"
```

When I use one of the above, for instance, I write `c = open(OUTPUT1)`.

However, I think the correct approach for this would be to have something like a generic:

`OUTPUT="/Users/check/$var.html"` and then while using, I should first assign:

```
$var = 1.html
then open(OUTPUT)
```

This way I open `1.html`.

How do you do this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to put it in a function:

```
def getPath(var):
  return "/Users/check/" + str(var) + ".html"

print(getPath(1))
print(getPath(2))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use string interpolation like so:

```
var = "1.html"
path = "/Users/check/{}".format(var)
open(path)
```

You may also want to use a more common pattern:

```
import os
var = "1.html"
path = os.path.join("/Users/check/", var)
open(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would consider using a tuple:

```
OUTPUT_PATHS = (
    '/Users/check/1.html',
    '/Users/check/2.html',
    '/tmp/3.html'
)
```

Then you can simply index them, starting with 0:

```
outnum = random(0, 3)
c = open(outnum)
```